# Packaging EJBs in Java EE server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have deployed an enterprise app in an EAR and a standalone web app in WAR (out side of the EAR) to the same Java EE server.

Question is can I access the local interface of the session bean in the EAR from the standalone WAR? if so can I use dependency injection (DI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer anyway to both your questions is **yes**.

Since both the ear and war are in the same JVM, a local interface can be used. To get an instance of the session bean, you would use the `global JNDI name` of said bean to do either a JNDI lookup or use with the mappedName property on the @EJB annotation. Those names are standardized via the following pattern:

`java:global[/<app-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>[!<fully-qualified-interface-name>]`

Lookup would thus be if the name of your ear is my_app, your bean is MyBean.java and its local interface is com.foo.SomeBeanLocal:

```
InitialContext ctx = InitialContext();
SomeBeanLocal someBean = (SomeBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("java:global/my_ear/SomeBean/com.foo.SomeBeanLocal");
```

Injection would be:

```
public SomeManagedClass {

    @EJB(mappedName="java:global/my_ear/SomeBean/com.foo.SomeBeanLocal")
    SomeBeanLocal someBean;
}
```

There are two catches however:

#### Non-standard naming

Older Java EE implementations (e.g. JBoss AS 5.1, Glassfish 2, Websphere) used their own naming pattern. E.g. JBoss AS 5.x would use:

`<app-name>/<bean-name>/local|global`

E.g. with the same names as the previous example, the global JNDI name of that bean in JBoss AS 5.1 would be:

`my_app/MyBean/local`

As said, other old application servers might use other names.

#### Startup-order

Especially with injection you have to assure somehow that the application you want to inject from has been started before the application you want to inject into. I.e. in your case that the EAR has been started before the standalone WAR. There are no standard mechanisms for this. You might be just lucky that it happens to be in the right order for you. This order might be influenced by time-stamps, alphabetical order of application names, or something else entirely.

JBoss AS for example uses `<depends>` tags in many of its proprietary configuration files, which is perfectly suited for this although it can be hard to find out what exactly you need to depend on (the syntax can be **very** cryptic).

Comment: Very informative, didn't realize that something so subtle as the startup-order would impact deployment. Thank you arjan.

Answer (score 4):

Section 3.2.2 of the EJB 3.1 specification explicitly states that this is not portable:

> Access to an enterprise bean through
>   the local client view is only required
>   to be supported for local clients
>   packaged within the same application
>   as the enterprise bean that provides
>   the local client view. Compliant
>   implementations of this specification
>   may optionally support access to the
>   local client view of an enterprise
>   bean from a local client packaged in a
>   different application. The
>   configuration requirements for
>   inter-application access to the local
>   client view are vendor-specific and
>   are outside the scope of this
>   specification. Applications relying on
>   inter-application access to the local
>   client view are non-portable.

In general, the solution will require at a minimum:

1. Some mechanism for allowing both the EAR and WAR class loaders to have visibility to the same interface class.
2. Some mechanism for looking up a local interface from another application.  For example, java:global.